# Value was evaluated just now with console.log on JavaScript object

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

When I print object in HTML using for each loop I'm getting only half contents of the object but when I print using `console.log` and press that little triangle I'm getting full object and ***i*** is shown near that object when I hover that it says value was evaluated just now as shown in below image,
[image]

When I print same object in HTML it looks like this,

```
7.33--Some Name
7.08--Some Name
7.83--Some Name
```

Actually, `object` contains a total of 5 elements as shown in the above image,
Code for printing object HTML,

```
for (var key in obj){
    $("p").append(key+"--"+obj[key][0]+"<br>");
}
```

Comment: Please include your code alongside the results

Comment: 1) Show your code. 2) The `console` outputs *live* data. You may be adding more data to your object after you've displayed its contents in your document.

Comment: Did you try console.dir instead of console.log?

Comment: `console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(object)))` perhaps - as long as it's JSONable :p

Comment: `print full object in html` - what does this even mean? what does html have to do with the console? (answer: nothing)

Answer (score 14):

Examining objects via `console.log` happens in an `asynchronous` manner.

The reference to the object is passed synchronously to console but it doesn't display the properties till its expanded . If the object has been modified before examining it in the console, the data shown will have the updated values. Chrome console shows a little `i` in a box which which says value below was evaluated just now

In order to print the object completely in console, you can stringify and log it like

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(obj));
```

Comment: How to print in html, I have tried doing like x=JSON.stringify(obj) and use x as object but thats not working.

Comment: After using JSON.stringify on obj, your obj will be converted to string, and hence things like obj.keyName won't work. In HTML you can directly do obj.keyName without stringifying

Comment: That's what i can't do, before accessing object it has to be evaluated that can be done in developer tool only by clicking that  small triangle arrow

Comment: So if I understand correctly, you need to add obj value to HTML, why do you need developerTool for that. Also if you directly print console.log(obj.keyName) then it will work properly, ie. with individual keyname

Comment: developer tool is for checking and console.log(obj) doesn't show full object until it is evaluated that's why when i print it using for each loop in html I'm getting half object only how do i get full object in html

Comment: How are you handling it in HTML, can you add the code for that