# The value of a property in an object is different from the value of directly accessing that property

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, resize, window

I'm trying to get the exact height of a div in React

```
    <div ref="pageContainer" className="flex flex-start">
      <div>
        <Title getTitleSize={this.getTitleSize} title={title} size={titleWidth} />
      </div>
      <div>
        {children}
      </div>
    </div>
```

By acessing the height of a div with offsetHeight

`componentDidMount(){
    this.refs.pageContainer.offsetHeight
    this.setState({divHeight: this.refs.pageContainer.offsetHeight + 'px'})
  }`

But I noticed that when directly accessing `this.refs.pageContainer.offsetHeight` it returns a different value than when looking up what the actual value is in the object `this.refs.pageContainer`

For example `this.refs.pageContainer.offsetHeight` will return `231` but when looking at the object the value is clearly `251`. It slightly changes the pixel values of other properties on that object as well. Why would the object not return the value it's supposed to have?

Also after the component updates if I access the same value in componentWillUpdate it returns the right value.

Comment: When you are accessing and assigning the value to state it may so happen that the height of the container is different, but after an update it has change and since console.log() prints the value a little later, you see the updated value

Comment: You might want to check this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44362783/value-below-was-evaluated-just-now-in-javascript-object/44362860#44362860