# Having trouble looping through array object to create list items

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, dictionary

I'm able to loop through JSON data to create an array filled with numbers, but when I go to create the list items it doesn't work. The component just renders an empty list.

When I console.log(ticketNumbers) right before the map function, it shows as a collapsed Array [] until I expand it (it then shows all the values)

```
function apiCall() {
  var ticketNumbers = [];
  var memId = 'xxx'; 
  var myInit = { 
      method: 'GET',
      mode: 'cors',
      headers: {
        'authorization': "xxx",
    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin':'*',
    'content-type': "application/json",
    'cache-control': "no-cache"
          },
      params: {
    'orderBy': 'status/name asc',
    'pageSize': 300,
    'conditions': "resources contains '" + memId + "' AND status/id not in (17,165,36,163,164,42,73,46,78,148,34,132,45,159,60,168,106,51,72,95)"
          }
  };
  axios.get('Url', myInit)
    .then((response) => {
      console.log(response.data)
      for (var ticket in response.data) {
        ticketNumbers.push(response.data[ticket].id)
      };  
     })
    return ticketNumbers
}
class TicketContainer extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      data: [],
      loading: true,
    };
  }
  componentWillMount() {
      this.setState({
        data: {
      numbers: apiCall()
        },      
      loading: false
        })
      };
  render() {
    return(
      <div>
    {this.state.loading ? 'Loading' : <Tickets data={this.state.data} />}
      </div>
    )
  }
}

class Tickets extends Component {
  render() {
    const stuff = this.props;
    var ticketList = stuff.data.numbers;
    console.log(ticketList);
    return(
      <div>
        <ul>Ticket Number
          {ticketList.map((ticket, index) => {
            return <li key={index}>sweet</li>;
          })}   
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: what is your json

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should correctly use Promise to solve this. First, let's change apiCall so that it will return a Promise:

```
function apiCall() {
  var ticketNumbers = [];
  var memId = 'xxx'; 
  var myInit = { 
      method: 'GET',
      mode: 'cors',
      headers: {
        'authorization': "xxx",
    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin':'*',
    'content-type': "application/json",
    'cache-control': "no-cache"
          },
      params: {
    'orderBy': 'status/name asc',
    'pageSize': 300,
    'conditions': "resources contains '" + memId + "' AND status/id not in (17,165,36,163,164,42,73,46,78,148,34,132,45,159,60,168,106,51,72,95)"
          }
  };
  return axios.get('Url', myInit)
    .then((response) => {
      console.log(response.data)
      for (var ticket in response.data) {
        ticketNumbers.push(response.data[ticket].id)
      }
      return ticketNumbers;
     });
}
```

You know have a Promise based api that can be used like this:

```
apiCall().then(ticketNumbers => console.log(ticketNumbers);
```

We just need to modify componentWillMount know:

```
componentWillMount() {
     apiCall().then(numbers => this.setState({ loading: false, data: numbers });
}
```

Comment: it's a suggestion let him know about the success and failure in promise. It'll be beneficial for him

Answer (score 0):

The apiCall function calls an API which is asynchronous process and returning `ticketNumbers` from function request **won't return the result** as the return statement will be executed before the API response is ready and `ticketNumbers` array is populated.

The easiest way for you to do this is to define this function in the React class and directly `setState` in the callback of `axios` request

```
class TicketContainer extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      data: [],
      loading: true,
    };
  }
  componentWillMount() {
      this.apiCall()

  };


  apiCall =() => {

      var memId = 'xxx'; 
      var myInit = { 
          method: 'GET',
          mode: 'cors',
          headers: {
            'authorization': "xxx",
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin':'*',
            'content-type': "application/json",
            'cache-control': "no-cache"
          },
          params: {
            'orderBy': 'status/name asc',
            'pageSize': 300,
            'conditions': "resources contains '" + memId + "' AND status/id not in (17,165,36,163,164,42,73,46,78,148,34,132,45,159,60,168,106,51,72,95)"
              }
      };
      axios.get('Url', myInit)
        .then((response) => {
          var ticketNumbers = [];
          for (var ticket in response.data) {
            ticketNumbers.push(response.data[ticket].id)
          }; 
          this.setState({data: ticketNumbers, loading: false}) 
         })
  }
  render() {
    return(
      <div>
    {this.state.loading ? 'Loading' : <Tickets data={this.state.data} />}
      </div>
    )
  }
}

class Tickets extends Component {
  render() {
    const stuff = this.props;
    var ticketList = stuff.data.numbers;
    console.log(ticketList);
    return(
      <div>
        <ul>Ticket Number
          {ticketList.map((ticket, index) => {
            return <li key={index}>sweet</li>;
          })}   
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

In case you are wondering why the console.log() statment logs the array, check this answer [Value below was evaluated just now in JavaScript object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44362783/value-below-was-evaluated-just-now-in-javascript-object/44362860#44362860)