# Saving an object inside itself

Tags: javascript, object

How come I can store an object as it's own property? Here is a simple example:

```
let obj = {};
obj['obj'] = obj;
```

This will result in having an infinite object tree: I can call `obj` with `obj.obj.obj.obj` or even with `obj.obj.obj.vobj.obj.obj.obj.obj`.

Is this an issue for performance? It doesn't seem to bother the browser at all.

Actually, when I look at the console in Chrome and click to expand `obj`'s properties it says (on the tooltip of <kbd>i</kbd>):

> Value below was evaluated **just now**

So they were evaluated just when I clicked to expand.

[image]

Does this mean that JavaScript too will not look at `obj`'s property until I actually access them?

**Is `obj.obj` just a reference to `obj`?**

Comment: I think you need to read up on the concept of "references". The object is not stored inside itself. It contains a _reference_ to itself.

Comment: _"Is obj.obj just a reference to obj"_ yes. Window and various other objects also have self references. `window.window.window`, `window.top.top.top` etc all just references to the same object

Comment: You can check this answer on [what value was evaluated just now means](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44362783/weird-behaviour-of-console-log-with-javascript-object/44362860#44362860)

Comment: Thank you all for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is this an issue for performance?

No. A circular reference is just as every other reference. Every class instance has actually a circular reference:

```
instance.constructor.prototype.constructor.protototype
```

> Is `obj.obj` just a reference to `obj`?

Yes.

> Does this mean that JavaScript too will not look at `obj`'s property until I actually access them?

Yes. And the console won't try to expand it as it would get caught up in an endless loop.

Comment: This is fun and it just happened to me. I tried expanding the obj in Firefox and it only went for around 30 times, and then the obj disappeared.