# Store character in 2-dimensional array

Tags: javascript

As you can see below, I'm trying to add characters in 2-dimensional array. But I'm not able to store it. Can anyone help me with that?
Thanks in advance.

```js
let gameBoard = [
  [1, 2, 3],
  [4, 5, 6],
  [7, 8, 9]
];

console.log(" ", + gameBoard[0][0] + " |", + gameBoard[0][1] + " | " + gameBoard[0][2]);
console.log(" ", + gameBoard[1][0] + " |", + gameBoard[1][1] + " | " + gameBoard[1][2]);
console.log(" ", + gameBoard[2][0] + " |", + gameBoard[2][1] + " | " + gameBoard[2][2]);

gameBoard[1][1] = "a";

console.log(" ", + gameBoard[0][0] + " |", + gameBoard[0][1] + " | " + gameBoard[0][2]);
console.log(" ", + gameBoard[1][0] + " |", + gameBoard[1][1] + " | " + gameBoard[1][2]);
console.log(" ", + gameBoard[2][0] + " |", + gameBoard[2][1] + " | " + gameBoard[2][2]);
```

Comment: Don't use `+` if you use `,` or viceversa

Comment: [Related](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44362860/1377002). Use [a template string](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) instead: ``console.log(` ${gameBoard[1][0]} | ${gameBoard[1][1]} | ${gameBoard[1][2]} `);``.

Comment: No issue in assigning characters. Try `console.log(gameBoard.map(g => g.join(' | ')).join('\n'))`

Answer (score 3):

Your main issue is not how you set the variable. Your main issue is your console log statement. You can verify this by simply using `console.log(gameBoard)`.

```
console.log(" ", + gameBoard[1][0] + " |", + gameBoard[1][1] + " | " + gameBoard[0][2]);
// Using both  ^ ^                 ^     ^ ^                 ^       ^
```

This means that the part that says `+ gameBoard[1][1]` is seen as `0 + gameBoard[1][1]` or `0 + "a"` which is not a number (NaN, as your code says).

You're mixing multiple arguments to the `console.log` function (,) with the concatenation operator (+). Use one of them instead of both:

```
console.log(" " + gameBoard[0][0] + " |" + gameBoard[0][1] + " | " + gameBoard[0][2]);
// Use +        ^                 ^      ^                 ^       ^

console.log(" ", gameBoard[0][0], " |", gameBoard[0][1], " | ", gameBoard[0][2]);
// Use ,       ^                ^     ^                ^      ^

console.log(` ${gameBoard[0][0]} |${gameBoard[0][1]} | ${gameBoard[0][2]}`);
// Use `    ^                                                            ^
```